# Need help with Raspberry Pi camera - mmal error

Tags: python, pi-4, update, picamera, mmal

Hello Raspberry Pi community,

I'm reaching out for assistance with a recurring error related to the Raspberry Pi camera module.

so it showing this error:

```
##################################################################

RuntimeWarning: This channel is already in use, continuing anyway.  Use GPIO.setwarnings(False) to disable warnings.
  GPIO.setup(LED_cam_PIN, GPIO.OUT)
[INFO] loading encodings + face detector...
mmal: mmal_port_event_send: event lost on port 1,0 (buffer header callback not defined)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/media/pi/AISHA BEN1/ALL_CODE/Theone.py", line 33, in <module>
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500)
  File "/home/pi/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/imutils/convenience.py", line 69, in resize
    (h, w) = image.shape[:2]
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute 'shape'

##############################################################
```

this is the code:

```python
import os
import face_recognition
import pickle
import time
import cv2
import imutils
from imutils.video import VideoStream
from imutils.video import FPS
import subprocess
import RPi.GPIO as GPIO

LED_cam_PIN = 13

# Set up GPIO
GPIO.setmode(GPIO.BCM)
GPIO.setup(LED_cam_PIN, GPIO.OUT)

currentname = "unknown"
encodingsP = "encodings.pickle"

print("[INFO] loading encodings + face detector...")
data = pickle.loads(open(encodingsP, "rb").read())

vs = VideoStream(usePiCamera=True).start()
time.sleep(2.0)

fps = FPS().start()
# Function to control the camera LED
def turn_on_camera_led():
    GPIO.output(LED_cam_PIN, GPIO.HIGH)
while True:
    frame = vs.read()
    frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=500)
    boxes = face_recognition.face_locations(frame)
    encodings = face_recognition.face_encodings(frame, boxes)
    names = []

    for encoding in encodings:
        matches = face_recognition.compare_faces(data["encodings"],
            encoding)
        name = "Unknown"
        subprocess.run(["python", "theething.py"])

        

        if True in matches:
            matchedIdxs = [i for (i, b) in enumerate(matches) if b]
            counts = {}

            for i in matchedIdxs:
                name = data["names"][i]
                counts[name] = counts.get(name, 0) + 1

            name = max(counts, key=counts.get)

            if currentname != name:
                currentname = name
                print(currentname)
                subprocess.run(["python", "door.py"])
                   
                

           
                

        names.append(name)

    for ((top, right, bottom, left), name) in zip(boxes, names):
        cv2.rectangle(frame, (left, top), (right, bottom),
            (0, 255, 225), 2)
        y = top - 15 if top - 15 > 15 else top + 15
        cv2.putText(frame, name, (left, y), cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX,
            .8, (0, 255, 255), 2)

    cv2.imshow("Facial Recognition is Running", frame)
    key = cv2.waitKey(1) & 0xFF

    if key == ord("q"):
        break

    fps.update()

fps.stop()
print("[INFO] elasped time: {:.2f}".format(fps.elapsed()))
print("[INFO] approx. FPS: {:.2f}".format(fps.fps()))

cv2.destroyAllWindows()
vs.stop()
```

Comment: It is a warning, not an error.  The warning message tells you what to do to stop the warning.  Not sure how us repeating that here can help you any further.

Comment: Your question is a mess. Don't understand which error you are referring to.